# Neo4jClient HTTPS Support

Tags: .net, https, neo4j, neo4jclient

i can't seem to make Neo4jclient to work with neo4j when HTTPS is enabled. Error happens at connect.

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("https://localhost:7473/db/data"));
                client.Connect();
```

It works perfectly fine when it's only HTTP.

This is what i am getting.

```
An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in Neo4jClient.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Has anyone ever tried to make Neo4jClient work with HTTPS support enabled. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, can you let me know what the inner exception is of the aggregate exception? If you navigate to the https endpoint in something like Chrome, do you get a certificate warning?

Comment: Exception is:System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is because of the certificate not being trusted for the SSL client, in development you can do this before beginning your connections:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

but this is **ONLY FOR DEVELOPMENT** don't do this in a production environment as it will make your code trust any and all certificates regardless. For production you'll need to trust any certificate you generate for the https endpoint.

`Neo4jClient` uses the `HttpClient` for it's connections and that balks at any non-trusted cert. Once the cert is trusted, the connections will work as for http.

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed problem with the self-signed certificate not being accepted.